# How to split a number into individual digits VB using substring

Tags: string, vb.net, substring

I tried to put seconds in 2 text-boxes, each digit in one. Example x= 56 x1= 5 and x2= 6

```
' s = TimeOfDay.Second
    TextBox15.Text = s.Substring(0, 1)
    TextBox16.Text = s.Substring(1, 1)'
```

When I try this I get the following error: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If `x` is and int, use division and modulo, not `Substring`. Or convert it to a string first.

Comment: thanks alot for you sugestion, i'll give that a try

Comment: If the number of seconds is less than 10, do you want a "0" or nothing at all in TextBox15?

Answer (score 0):

ArgumentOutOfRange exceptions occurs whenever you attempt to get a character that doesn't exist at the given position. So what is happening is that there is either not a String at position 0 with a length of 1 or there is not a String at position 1 with a length of 1.

To prevent this, add a simple If/Then statement to check if the length of the original String at least equal to the position of the character. Also for what it's worth, since you only want one letter, simply get the character at the desired index of the String.

Here is a quick example:

```
If s.Length >= 1 Then
    TextBox15.Text = s(0).ToString()
End If
If s.Length >= 2 Then
    TextBox16.Text = s(1).ToString()
End If
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fqp3Wh)

Comment: If the seconds were to tick over from 59 to 0 then the "5" would still be showing in TextBox16.

Comment: The OP was asking specifically about how to get one digit into its respective TextBox.

Comment: Realistically, it is likely that the seconds could be updated at some time. It is not difficult to adjust your code to take that into consideration with an `Else TextBox16.Text = ""`. Perhaps it would be a good idea to ask the OP for clarification to avoid the use of the crystal ball.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to a string before getting the digits, just doing the maths to get them will work well enough:

```
Dim rightNow = DateTime.Now
TextBox15.Text = (rightNow.Second \ 10).ToString()
TextBox16.Text = (rightNow.Second Mod 10).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

And another approach.

```
Dim c() As Char = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00").ToArray
TextBox1.Text = c(0)
TextBox2.Text = c(1)
```

Comment: If DateTime.Now.Second < 10 then c(1) does not exist. Using `DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00")` or `DateTime.Now.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0"c)` would solve the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you, I didn't think it through and only tested a bit.